# Stored procedure that filters results to one reading every nth second

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query a table that contains time series records and filter the results to return one reading every nth second.

For example, return records between StartDate and EndDate but don't return every record, return one record for every 3,600 seconds so one reading per hour.

In .NET I can do this using code like this.

```
var TimeStepResults = allResults.Aggregate((x, y) => 
    Math.Abs(x.From.Ticks - counter) < Math.Abs(y.From.Ticks - counter) ? x : y);
```

However I don't want to return millions of records and then pull out one record every hour or 30 minutes, I'd prefer to just return filtered records from the stored procedure.

Can anyone suggest how this could be done?

Comment: between StartDate and EndDate?  Not StartTime and EndTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your C# code correctly, it seeks for the row with the `From` value closest to `counter`.  In SQL, you can do this like:

```
declare @counter datetime = '2015-07-18 11:00'

select  convert(varchar(13), [from], 120)
,       col1
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by convert(varchar(13), [from], 120) -- yyyy-mm-dd HH
                    order by abs(datediff(second, [from], @counter))
                    ) as rn
        ,       *
        from    Measurements
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- only row closest to @counter per hourly group
```

The query creates one row per hour using `partition by convert(varchar(13), [from], 120)`. The `convert` function formats the `[from]` column as a `yyyy-mm-dd HH` datetime, like `2015-07-18 11`.

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03894/2/0)

Comment: This looks like a good solution, I'm just trying to work one thing out before its complete. We're being passed a start and finish datetime, an id which we use in the query and the number of seconds we should filter results by so the most common one is 3,600 to indicate we should return one result for each hour. This query sounds like it would fit that scenario. But what if we were passed 1,800 to indicate every 30 minutes? I could insist on a fixed list of options like every 1 minute, 30 minutes, hour, day etc but how would this query allow me to provide those other filter values?

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to creating a job for this (.net job or SQL job) that will run in every 30 minute. And it can call some stored procedure that will return your preferred result.

If in case if error, you can write to system events or table for tracking.